# How to right callback newsfeed JSON pass single api category_name

Tags: android, json, callback

How to pass the newsfeed `category_name` callback in JSON. `public newsfeed newsfeed = null;` App crashes while writing.

JSON API this:

```
object      {8}
    status   :ok
featured        [1]
category        [5]
menu        [5]
shopmenu
    
newsfeed        [1]
    cid :28
   category_name    :mobile
   recipes_count    :5
```

This callback data

```
 public class CallbackHome implements Serializable {
 public String status = "";

public List<Recipe> featured = new ArrayList<>();


public List<Category> category = new ArrayList<>();
public List<menu> menu = new ArrayList<>();




public List<shopmenu> shopmenu = new ArrayList<>();



public newsfeed newsfeed = null;


public List<Recipe> recent = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Recipe> videos = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

How to right callback newsfeed data `category_name` how to pass news feed category name single data only.

```
displayData2(responseHome.newsfeed);

category_name = root_view.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);

public void displayData2(final newsfeed newsfeed) {

    category_name.setText(newsfeed.category_name);


}
```

model class

```
public class newsfeed implements Serializable {

public int cid = -1;
public String category_name;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to naming convention rules of java, a `Class` name should always start with a capital letter.

Since, `newsfeed` is a java class it should be renamed to `NewsFeed`.

[Read more about Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Since, you are receiving array of `newsfeed` in your API response you also need to refactor your newsfeed vairable declaration in `CallbackHome` class as follows

```
public ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsfeed = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: not working bro error https://ibb.co/JtBCrv6
https://ibb.co/s3kMPg8

Comment: news feed json this  category_name    :mobile  pass  textview

Comment: watch description i will update bro

Comment: category_name    :mobile  category text newstriger text bro

Comment: Okay, do you have a separate model class for `newsfeed` ? If yes, please post that.

Comment: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2834 path $.newsfeed  error

Comment: check bro i will update  model class

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try that.

Comment: change model class captical firsr letter error show Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2834 path $.newsfeed

Comment: In you `CallbackHome` class, make newsfeed an array

Comment: newsfeed how to pass only single data category_name = root_view.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);    model public String category_name;

Comment: Choudhary https://ibb.co/r6sFdPP